# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Below is the exception thrown when a detached criteria is executed :

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [S1000]; error code [156]; Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
2021-09-28 20:42:03,882 [mailTimerFactory-1] TRACE org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor  - Completing transaction for [com.test.service.impl.MailManagerImpl.processMails]
```

I have debugged with hibernate sourcecode and got the sql query being generated as I couldn't get to print the sql for the criteria even after turning showsql to true. Below is the query generated :

```
[org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader(select this_.cid as cid9_0_, this_.msgfrom as msgfrom9_0_, this_.msgto as msgto9_0_, this_.msgcc as msgcc9_0_, this_.msubject as msubject9_0_, this_.body as body9_0_, this_.createDate as createDate9_0_, this_.mailDate as mailDate9_0_, this_.expiryDate as expiryDate9_0_, this_.mailsent as mailsent9_0_, this_.remarks as remarks9_0_, this_.html as html9_0_ from mail_queue this_ where this_.mailsent=? and (this_.mailDate is null or this_.mailDate<=?) and (this_.expiryDate is null or this_.expiryDate>=?))]
```

I have copied the select query and was able to successfully execute it in SQL Server which makes me wonder what was causing the issue. If the column names contain any SQL keyword then it wouldn't be executed, right? There are no spaces in the column names as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit : Below is the sql trace :

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P0 bit,@P1 datetime,@P2 datetime,@P3 int,@P4 int',N'WITH query AS (select this_.cid as cid9_0_, this_.ms, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr__gfrom as msgfrom9_0_, this_.msgto as msgto9_0_, this_.msgcc as msgcc9_0_, this_.msubject as msubject9_0_, this_.body as body9_0_, this_.createdate as createdate9_0_, this_.maildate as maildate9_0_, this_.expirydate as expirydate9_0_, this_.mailsent as mailsent9_0_, this_.remarks as remarks9_0_, this_.html as html9_0_ from [mail_queue] this_ where this_.mailsent= @P0  and (this_.maildate is null or this_.maildate<= @P1 ) and (this_.expirydate is null or this_.expirydate>= @P2 )) SELECT * FROM query WHERE __hibernate_row_nr__ >=  @P3  AND __hibernate_row_nr__ <  @P4 ',1
select @p1
```

The query is malformed at `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr__gfrom as msgfrom9_0_`. How can I solve this? It turns out that removing the firstresult and maxresults parameters fixes this :

> original

```
getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria, 0, 250)
```

> after removing

```
getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria)
```

I believe the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr_` part is added because of the adding firstresult and maxresults parameters and hibernate is using the rownumber to filter the number of records. I cannot remove the limit parameters as it would fetch all the records in the table. I have used the parameters in many other detached criteria but strangely it is malformed in this case. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Run a SQL trace (Extended Events or Profiler) to capture the actual query sent to SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the query sent to the SQL server is indeed different. I have added the query received from profiler and added my findings. Why is the query malformed?

Comment: Is the column name 'from' a keyword in any way? I couldn't find a reference for the same. Also the same detachedcriteria was working fine on hibernate 3 and spring 3, but is facing the above issue on hibernate 4 and spring 4.1.6.

Comment: This is the problem column in the query, which as 2 `AS` clauses:` `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr__gfrom as msgfrom9_0_`.

Comment: Yes, hibernate is creating the query. The generated query should have been shomething like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr_, this_.msgfrom as msgfrom9_0_`. How can this be rectified?

Comment: Looks like a hibernate bug. Are you using the latest? Maybe someone can suggest a work-around.

Comment: I was thinking the same. I am using Hibernate 4.0 now. But I wont be able to update to hibernate 4.3 as it will break jtds driver and more. I just hope there is a version below 4.3 that can work in my case. Thanks for the help. I wouldn't have ever though that the trace query would be different from the one generated by hibernate criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug, but you can debug `org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.SQLServer2005LimitHandler#processSql` to see what goes wrong and even apply a custom workaround as you can replace the `LimitHandler` in a custom `Dialect`.